# How to pass a list of pandas columns to a pyplot chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

Here is my code, which works fine as far as it goes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'foo' : [1, 2, 7, 2],
    'bar' : [3, 1, 3, 2],
    'spam' : [5, 2, 1, 0]
    })

x = range(len(df.foo))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.stackplot(x, df.foo, df.bar, df.spam)
# plt.savefig('stackedarea.png')
plt.show()
```

[image: Stacked area chart]

My question is, how can I pass a list so I don't have to explicitly type out every column (Df.foo, df.bar...)?

I'm still a rank beginner at lambda functions and list comprehensions, I suspect one or the other is required.

(1) My first idea, to pass a list of column names

```
columnlist = ['foo', 'bar']
# snip
ax.stackplot(x, #something_goes_here) #I tried df[columnlist[, no joy
```

(2) My second idea, to pass a list of columns:

```
columnlist = ['foo', 'bar']
#here is where I don't know how to transform column list so it becomes
# passedlist, where passedlist = [df.foo, df.bar]
# snip
ax.stackplot(x, df[columnlist])
```

Hopefully I've explained well enough. I've only been doing python for a few weeks, please don't snicker out loud!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you want to plot all the columns you can do:

```
ax.stackplot(x, *[ts for col, ts in df.iteritems()])
```

if only a subset:

```
ax.stackplot(x, *[df[col] for col in ['foo', 'bar']])
```

note the `*` in above lines.

*edit*: you can also pass a 2-dimensional array to `stackplot`, so the simpler notation is:

```
ax.stackplot(x, df.T)  # all columns
ax.stackplot(x, df[['foo','bar']].T)  # only foo & bar columns
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you, I comprehend the list comprehension in your comprehensive list.

Comment: This question and answer need to be way more visible and easier to access. Took me some digging.